# ICS file rendering raw HTML when opened in Microsoft Outlook 2016 but not in MS Outlook 2013

Tags: c#, outlook-2013, outlook-2016

I have ICS file which is created from T4 template as follows.

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
PRODID:-//Microsoft Corporation//Outlook 11.0 MIMEDIR//EN
VERSION:2.0
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTART:20190129T013000Z
DTend:20190129T023000Z
SUMMARY;ENCODING=QUOTED-PRINTABLE: Hasitha Dananjaya
LOCATION;ENCODING=QUOTED-PRINTABLE: 
DESCRIPTION;CONTENT-TYPE:text/html:ENCODING=QUOTED-PRINTABLE:<p>test test</p><p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p><p>test line 2</p>=0D=0A=0D=0A
X-ALT-DESC;FMTTYPE=text/html:<p>test test</p><p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p><p>test line 2</p>
X-MICROSOFT-CDO-BUSYSTATUS:BUSY
CATEGORIES:Business
PRIORITY:3
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

When its opened from MS Outlook 2016 it shows raw html values as follows.
[image]

But same file opened in MS Outlook 2013
[image]

I did make sure both of the clients are running HTML mode.

I'm just trying to figure out what could be the root cause for this. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actual issue was with DESCRIPTION and X-ALT-DESC fields.

According to RFC2445 DESCRIPTION is to specify the plain text body of an appointment and X-ALT-DESC is there to provide alternate format for the DESCRIPTION property with HTML.

[RFC - DESCRIPTION](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee157602(v=exchg.80).aspx)

[RFC - X-ALT-DESC](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee237480(v=exchg.80).aspx)

Somehow MS OUTLOOK 2013 reads X-ALT-DESC by default where OUTLOOK 2016 reads DESCRIPTION by default. 2016 falls back to X-ALT-DESC only when DESCRIPTION is not there.

Therefore, Fix was to keep ICS file as follows.

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
PRODID:-//Microsoft Corporation//Outlook 11.0 MIMEDIR//EN
VERSION:2.0
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTART:20190201T013000Z
DTend:20190201T023000Z
SUMMARY;ENCODING=QUOTED-PRINTABLE: Hasitha Dananjaya
LOCATION;ENCODING=QUOTED-PRINTABLE: 
DESCRIPTION:\naaaaaaaaaaaaa\naaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa\naaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa\nbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
X-ALT-DESC;FMTTYPE=text/html:<p>aaaaaaaaaaaaa</p><p>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</p><p>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</p><p>bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb</p>
X-MICROSOFT-CDO-BUSYSTATUS:BUSY
CATEGORIES:Business
PRIORITY:3
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

Answer (score 1):

Do reverse engineering, create the file from Outlook 2016. Save the ICS file and open and view the content.

Then use this content to replace the logic how it generates.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I did that and found out a way to figure the actual RC.